# How to add a border to a circular image with mask

Tags: ios, swift, mask, cashapelayer

This is my attempt:

```
func round() {
    let width = bounds.width < bounds.height ? bounds.width : bounds.height
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(bounds.midX - width / 2, bounds.midY - width / 2, width, width)).CGPath

    self.layer.mask = mask

    // add border
    let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    frameLayer.path = mask.path
    frameLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
    frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    frameLayer.fillColor = nil

    self.layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
}
```

It works on the iphone 6 simulator (storyboard has size of 4.7), but on the 5s and 6+ it looks weird:

[image]

[image]

Is this an auto layout issue? Without the border, auto layout works correct. This is my first time working with masks and so I am not sure if what I have done is correct.

`round` function is called in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Read the description of `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, it tells when the method is going to be called and it doesn't look to be perfect for what you want to achieve.

Comment: And what is my alternative ?

Comment: Make a subclass of the view class, store a reference to your added path and layer, modify them when the size changes are detected (use `layoutSubviews` for that), reuse it in the future.

Comment: can you give me an example ? I am new at this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have subclassed `UIImageView`, for example, you can override `layoutSubviews` such that it (a) updates the mask; (b) removes any old border; and (c) adds a new border. In Swift 3:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class RoundedImageView: UIImageView {

    /// saved rendition of border layer

    private weak var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // create path

        let width = min(bounds.width, bounds.height)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY), radius: width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: .pi * 2, clockwise: true)

        // update mask and save for future reference

        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask

        // create border layer

        let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        frameLayer.path = path.cgPath
        frameLayer.lineWidth = 32.0
        frameLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        frameLayer.fillColor = nil

        // if we had previous border remove it, add new one, and save reference to new one

        borderLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        layer.addSublayer(frameLayer)
        borderLayer = frameLayer
    }
}
```

That way, it responds to changing of the layout, but it makes sure to clean up any old borders.

By the way, if you are not subclassing `UIImageView`, but rather are putting this logic inside the view controller, you would override `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead of `layoutSubviews` of `UIView`. But the basic idea would be the same.

--

By the way, I use a mask in conjunction with this shape layer because if you merely apply rounded corners of a `UIView`, it can result in weird artifacts (look at very thin gray line at lower part of the circular border):

[image: artifact]

If you use the bezier path approach, no such artifacts result:

[image: no artifact]

For Swift 2.3 example, see [earlier revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32187120/1).

Comment: What a great answer. This fixes all of my problems. Much appreciate it.

Comment: Worked smoothly but can't we do this from draw method?

Comment: Wow. Great answer. So many similar questions on SA that fail to solve this problem.

Comment: @NikhilManapure - Yes you can manually mask and render in the [`draw(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622529-draw) method, but we generally avoid that because we theoretically lose any optimizations/features that Apple’s implemented. Plus, this is a general mechanism that you can use regardless of the type of view or whatever subviews it might have.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to manipulate the `layer` of the image view itself.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
imageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor.CGColor
imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

You can include this in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `layoutSubviews` to make sure the size is always correct.

NB: Maybe this technique makes your circle mask obsolete ;-). As a rule of thumb, always choose the simplest solution.

Comment: I was using this, but to much problem with auto layout

Comment: So you should be using this and solve your auto layout issues.

Comment: I'd add `imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true`.

Comment: I ment I was using this solution with cornerRadius, also setting masktoBounds = true, but my image needs to resize when running on different screens and had many issues with this, that I couldn't resolve them, so I said I should try masking.

Comment: The `cornerRadius` approach is notorious for introducing undesirable artifacts when you look really closely at the corners. I'd suggest fixing the `UIBezierPath` approach (as A-Live suggested in comments above).

Comment: Put your resizing logic into the `layoutSubviews` override. You can then use the `cornerRadius` technique or masking, as you prefer.

Comment: @Rob not with `width / 2.0`. Perfect circles.

Comment: @Mundi: yes, your solution works, but I want to press a button and then the circular image view should get smaller, but after getting smaller it is not a perfect circle anymore. I am not sure if this aproach is bad or it's something with auto layout.

Comment: Btw, sorry for the noob question but how do I have access to layoutSubviews ? what do I need to override ?

Comment: @Mundi - Yes, sometimes even with `width / 2.0`, the `cornerRadius` approach can have problems. First a `UIBezierPath` with `bezierPathWithArcCenter` is sometimes smoother than corner radius approach (or `ovalInRect` approach). Second, you definitely can end up with weird little artifacts (see http://i.stack.imgur.com/DrRHu.png for an example) with `cornerRadius` approach. Don't get me wrong, sometimes `cornerRadius` works wonderfully, in which case you should use it. But in other cases, it really stinks and the `UIBezierPath` approach generates far more elegant results.

Comment: @Rob This is interesting. Perhaps, if you have time, you should post a question and answer it yourself (with screenshots) for the benefit or others.

Comment: This actually has been asked before. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/31602251 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/28822940 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/30124896 for a few.